# HttpURLConnection .getInputStream() Crashes on Marshmallow not Oreo

Tags: android, rest, web

The following code works flawlessly on Android 8. On a tablet running 6 it crashes when getting the getinputstream with a file io error. I've tried for HOURS and HOURS without any luck. PLEASE help. Nothing works. Even trying a volley doesn't help. My Web API works great on a computer and a phone.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/dmnugent80/repos");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return result.toString();
}
```

---

LOG CAT HERE

---

> 06-24 02:01:21.813 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase
>   I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0 06-24 02:01:21.813
>   22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase D/libc-netbsd:
>   [getaddrinfo]: hostname=recipedatabase.gear.host; servname=(null);
>   netid=0; mark=0
>       [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0 06-24 02:01:21.817
>   22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase D/libc-netbsd:
>   [getaddrinfo]: hostname=recipedatabase.gear.host; servname=(null);
>   netid=0; mark=0 06-24 02:01:21.818
>   22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase D/libc-netbsd:
>   [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024;
>   ai_family=0 06-24 02:01:21.824
>   22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase D/libc-netbsd:
>   getaddrinfo: recipedatabase.gear.host get result from proxy gai_error
>   = 0 06-24 02:01:21.824 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase I/System.out: [CDS]rx
>   timeout:0 06-24 02:01:21.826
>   22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase I/System.out:
>   [socket][0] connection
>   recipedatabase.gear.host/204.246.56.80:80;LocalPort=43028(0)
>       [CDS]connect[recipedatabase.gear.host/204.246.56.80:80] 06-24 02:01:21.826 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase D/Posix:
>   [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase :80 
>   06-24 02:01:21.919 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase
>   I/System.out: [CDS]port[43028]
>       [socket][/192.168.1.163:43028] connected 06-24 02:01:21.920 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase I/System.out: [CDS]rx
>   timeout:0
>       [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0 06-24 02:01:21.921 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase I/System.out:
>   [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
>       [OkHttp] sendRequest<< 06-24 02:01:21.982 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://recipedatabase.gear.host/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsonfindtable/SELECT
>   UnitID, UnitName, HiddenFlag FROM TblUnits ORDER BY UnitName FOR JSON
>   PATH
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>           at com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase.MainActivity.getRestFromWebAsString(MainActivity.java:334)
>           at com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase.MainActivity$MyAsyncInitialLoad.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:252)
>           at com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase.MainActivity$MyAsyncInitialLoad.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:232)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 06-24 02:01:21.983 22840-22890/com.marcusengineering.recipedatabase
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Can you update your question with error log from logcat?

Comment: See updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINNNNNNNALY FIGURED IT OUT!.

Not sure which ones were 100% needed but here's what I did to help any other poor souls.

1. Ensure that your web api is fomratted without the extra wrapping added from WCF, i.e. is plain text. (not critical)
2. Get rid of spaces in your URL. It appears OREO does this for you. Earlier versions must not. The code to do this is: **URL url = new URL(query.replace(" ","%20"));**
3. Happy dance

In totality the call should be as follows:

```
            URL url = new URL(query.replace(" ","%20"));
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        int i = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream inputs;
        if (i < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            inputs = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            // Error
            inputs = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            return "-1";
        }

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
```

To set the formatting to raw string in the WCF see the following.

In the *****.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet( UriTemplate = "jsonFindTableBare/{id}")] 
    Stream DoWork(string id);
```

In the svc.cs

```
public Stream DoWork(String id)
    {

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        String str = "YOUR RESPONSE HERE";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
    }
```

Thanks for all the help, Mangal. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You should first check response code to also handle the error input stream.

```
InputStream inputs;
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            inputs = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            // Error
            inputs = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
        }
```

then call

```
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection);
```

I had also faced some app crashing experience because of handling error stream direclty.
Please do check always, It's a good practice.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I had this. However every call just throws an error and no data is read.

Comment: urlConnection.getErrorStream() returns a null :(

Comment: same code worked for me on both versions here? What marshmellow device you are testing on??Is it virtual or regular device??

Comment: Tab 2. Also fails on an older htc version 5 android. The code works on all devices from a generic site such as: http://resttesttest.com/

However, for my web api which is formatted the exact same it fails ...

Comment: What response code you are getting for your web api.?check about that response code also..

Comment: There is no method like getResponseCode() in URLConnection class.